# Which reliability index (if any) is appropriate?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, count-data, reliability

Subjects were asked to endorse whether or not they have experienced various negative events (yes/no). I want to use a measure that is a sum of how many events they have experienced. Since this measure is just a count (albeit a count of different items), what's the appropriate type of reliability measure to use? Is a **reliability analysis** even applicable in this instance?

Comment: I don't think reliability analysis is appropriate here. I think these are formative indicators. See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3889475/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your question is.

If you want to know if these sum scores are consistent over time (within each participant), you would need participants to fill out the questions multiple times; you could then use various measures of intra-rater reliability such as a weighted kappa or intraclass correlation coefficient.

If you want to know if these sum scores differ between groups of participants or are influenced by covariates, this is more appropriately a job for general linear models such as ANOVA or regression.

Finally, if you want to know if the items you are summing together are really tapping the same underlying construct, this is more appropriately a job for latent variable modeling such as factor analysis or SEM.